# Porting allegro 4 to allegro 5

Tags: c++, opengl, allegro, allegro5

what is the allegro 5 version of this function?

```
texture_number = allegro_gl_make_texture_ex(AGL_TEXTURE_MASKED, my_bitmap, GL_RGBA);
```

Or do I need to do something completely different in allegro 5? I'm trying to load an image to be used as an openGL texture. Here is the full code.

```
GLuint texture_number;
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *my_bitmap;

my_bitmap = al_load_bitmap("terrainImages/ground_32.bmp");
texture_number = allegro_gl_make_texture_ex(AGL_TEXTURE_MASKED, my_bitmap, GL_RGBA);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_number);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allegro 5 always uses either OpenGL or D3D. Therefore, all Allegro bitmaps are already textures. To get the OpenGL texture object associated with an Allegro bitmap, call `al_get_opengl_texture`. Note that due to sub-bitmaps, multiple bitmaps can use the same texture. So you will need to use `al_get_opengl_texture_size` and `al_get_opengl_texture_position` to get the location within the texture for that bitmap.

Comment: Allegro also supports memory bitmaps, so not all bitmaps are textures.